# Could the video recorder of Blair Witch Project (original) last as long as it did?

Tags: realism, blair-witch-project

I live next door to one of the producers of "Blair Witch Project," ([1999](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0185937/)) so that got me to watch the movie.

Not recalling how long a personal home video recorder could work, I was wondering whether a two day hike that turned into a horror might have been recorded, should it have really happened.  I realize it's just a movie, but we can see 90 minutes or so, and the implication is that there is much more.

I'm curious if **the amateur filming of Blair Witch Project could have happened** (and how)?

Comment: @Paulie_D I'm assuming without an energy source, there was no recharging.  If there could be a replacement battery, I'd be interested to know how many there would need to be and when it could be done.  PS - I'm happy to just enjoy a movie, but wanted to know.

Comment: @Paulie_D - I'm happy to have it migrated, but not sure where it should have landed.  I reckoned movie buffs might have previous input about movies with this kind of film technique (Cloverfield, et al).   Maybe the question should have been about how it is reconciled.

Comment: "found-footage" is the term I'm familiar with for this technique of making an entire movie look like it was shot on in-character camcorders or smart phones.  IIRC, Blair Witch was the movie that coined that term, in fact.

Answer (score 5):

The action is shot on **two** cameras. A 16mm film camera [black and white] (which uses film magazines) and an RCA Hi8 Camcorder [color].

[image]

[image]

They state in the first few minutes [c.2:25] of the film that...

> "We've got so much fuckin' battery power we could.... .fuel a small world country for a month."

So, assuming the film magazines and camcorder tapes/cassettes (whatever) were recovered...which is the conceit...then they seem to have been well supplied with batteries to power both devices.